# How to extend parent theme sections and settings to Options Tree

Tags: child-theme, theme-options, plugin-option-tree

I am developing a child theme based on a theme that use Option Tree for it's options.

Is it possible to add a new section with my child theme settings to the already defined sections by parent theme ?

The only reference I found was https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree-theme/issues/3 but I couldn't implemented. I also read a lot the Option Tree code but couldn't find the appropriate filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who want to achieve the same thing :

```
add_filter( ot_settings_id() . '_args', 'my_ot_setting');

function my_ot_setting($custom_settings){

//do some work with the settings and the sections, ie append your settings.

return $custom_settings;
}
```

This works if the parent theme applies this filter before saving the options like the example here : https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree-theme/blob/master/inc/theme-options.php#L833

Otherwise you have to do it yourself like the example above.

Comment: This is like hundred of years old , and OT its been maintained by other person , but I can't extend any function like you @Laxmana said 3  years ago